# how to remove variable sharing between objects?

Tags: c++, qt, class, oop, sharing

Hi i am new to object oriented programming. here I intent to make three animation plots

```
subwindow_movie *child_Movie = new subwindow_movie;
child_Movie->setGeometry(20,100,620,560);
child_Movie->setplot(0);
child_Movie->show();

subwindow_movie *child_Movie1 = new subwindow_movie;
child_Movie1->setGeometry(680,100,620,560);
child_Movie1->setplot(1);
child_Movie1->show();


subwindow_movie *child_Movie2 = new subwindow_movie;
child_Movie2->setGeometry(325,350,620,560);
child_Movie2->setplot(2);
child_Movie2->show();
```

but the problem is that they all share same  value of `setplot` i,e when the third `subwindow_movie` is created `child_movie0` and `child_movie1` both `setplot` values become `2`; how to get rid of that... below is the set value function inside the class

```
#include "subwindow_movie.h"
#include "ui_subwindow_movie.h"

#include "plot.h"

#include <qapplication.h>

#include <qmainwindow.h>

int movie;

subwindow_movie::subwindow_movie(QWidget *parent) :

    QDialog(parent),

    ui(new Ui::subwindow_movie)

{

    ui->setupUi(this);

}

subwindow_movie::~subwindow_movie()
{
    delete ui;
}

void subwindow_movie::setplot(int value)

{
     if (value ==0)

     {   d_plot0 = new Plot( this );

         movie=0;}

     else if (value ==1)

     {   d_plot1 = new Plot( this );

         movie=1;}

     else if (value ==2)

     {   d_plot2 = new Plot( this );

         movie=2;}

}


void subwindow_movie::on_movie_slider_valueChanged(int value)

{
    if (movie ==0)

    {  d_plot0->setAlpha(value);

       }
    else if (movie ==1)

    {  d_plot1->setAlpha(value);

    }
    else if (movie ==2)

    {  d_plot2->setAlpha(value);

    }
}
```

the real problem is `int movie` which changes for with the creation of new `child_movie` causes the `child_movie0` to run `movie2`. i dont want the `movie` variable changed for the `child_movie0` with the creation of `child_movie1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

`int movie;`

there is only one instance of the `movie` variable (it is a **global variable**). Each time you set its value, the previous value is overwritten.

Make `movie` a **member variable** instead:

```
class subwindow_movie {
    int movie;

public:

    ...
}
```

Then, `movie` is available as separate instance for each `subwindow_movie` object you are creating. Inside the `subwindow_movie` methods, you can still access the variable as before.

Essentially, you should never use global variables - see also http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables: **Why global variables are evil**

Comment: tried your suggestion but still movie value is changing with new child_movie declaration.. :(

Comment: @user3871970 Good :) Is there anything specifically what you additionally had to do, and what I can add to my answer?

Comment: no there were some other g_variables i overlooked in first place.